# General solution of the first order differential equation $y'=(x+y−1)^2,$ where $x, y$ are real?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone help me solve this.

Which one of the following is the general solution of the first order differential equation

> $$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=(x+y−1)^2, \text { where } x, y \text { are real }$$

(A)  $Y=1+x+\tan^{-1}(x+c)$, where $c$ is a constant.

(B) $ Y=1+x+\tan(x+c)$, where $c$ is a constant.

(C)  $Y=1-x+\tan^{-1}(x+c)$, where $c$ is a constant

(D)  $Y=1-x+\tan(x+c)$, where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: It's better to post your attempt...

Comment: I don't know how to approach this ODE because of square in RHS.

Comment: Well I gave  a substitution then separate and integrate Nikh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$y'=(x+y−1)^2, \text { where } x, y \text { are real }$$
Substitute $z=x+y-1 \implies z'=1+y'$

Comment: You should be able to solve your DE....Just substitute in your original equaion $z,z'$ @Nikh

Comment: $z'=\frac {dz}{dx}$ in my post @Nikh Once you substitute you only have z z' and $x$ variable.

Comment: Oh   Thank you ..

Comment: You're welcome @Nikh